# Get next work-item in Django with PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, concurrency, race-condition

Imagine you have a simple table with work-items:

```
|ID |OWNER|...
+---+-----+---
|123|     |...
|456|     |...
|789|     |...
```

We want to provide a http API to get the next work-item which does not have an owner yet.

We use PostgreSQL.

We access the table with Django-ORM.

I guess there are several race-conditions if the API gets access simultaneously by many users.

How can I ensure with the given tools (PostgreSQL, Django) that all race conditions are solved (it is a major fault if a work-item is given to two ore more users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Django 1.11, [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update) started supporting `skip_locked`. This means you can save on `save()` calls since you don't have to assign it to an owner right away.

For example, building on top of @user73657's answer:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    work_item = WorkItem.objects.select_for_update().filter(owner__isnull=True).first()
    work_item.owner = request.user
    work_item.save(update_fields=['owner'])

# process work_item
```

you can do:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    work_item = WorkItem.objects.select_for_update(skip_locked=True).filter(owner__isnull=True).first()
    work_item.owner = request.user
    # process work_item, edit other fields
    work_item.save()
```

With `skip_locked=True`, the transaction skips the locked row, and is therefore non-blocking. As a bonus, you'll only need to save to the db *once*.

Comment: wow, `SKIP LOCKED` looks good. I found this post: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/ which explains details.

Answer (score 1):

With `select_for_update`:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    work_item = WorkItem.objects.select_for_update().filter(owner__isnull=True).first()
    work_item.owner = request.user
    work_item.save(update_fields=['owner'])

# process work_item
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

`select_for_update` will make sure that only one connection can update the matching rows until the transaction has ended.